# Cannot get all running Android processes

Tags: android, process

I want to get all running processes in my phone. I have tried this code

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) 
                     getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

But this code returns only my process.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> listProcess = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(RunningAppProcessInfo runningProInfo:listProcess){
        Log.i("Running Processes", ":"+runningProInfo.processName);
}
```

Working code.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you so much. But this code returns only process that is running right now. I'm going to write a service which is looking for some application that user has started.  Maybe this code doesn't return all background processes, because I don't have root permissions?

Comment: then it require rooted device

Comment: I tried this code, but it returns only my application